# ons-toolbar-button programmatically enable disable

Tags: onsen-ui

I have

```
<ons-toolbar-button id="buttonNext" disabled >Next</ons-toolbar-button>
```

and I want to programmatically enable it or disable it again.

I found that in ons-button, there is methods like setDisabled(true) but not for ons-toolbar-button.

Could someone shed some light on how to programmatically enable/disable ons-toolbar-button?
    thanks.

Comment: I also need this, I've created an issue on github for this https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/1121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toolbar buttons are usually removed or hidden rather than disabled, that's why there are no methods for `ons-toolbar-button`. `setDisabled` just adds `disabled` attribute to the element, nothing else. You can implement it for `ons-toolbar-button` like this:

```
setDisabled = function(boolean) {
  if (boolean) {
    document.querySelector('ons-toolbar-button').setAttribute('disabled', '');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('ons-toolbar-button').removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}
```

Then of course you need some CSS:

```
ons-toolbar-button[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Check it out here: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/PZZwMv